# Custom value on python unicode \u

Tags: python, unicode

I'm quite new to python and i've been trying to get this working with no success.
Is there any way to make something like this work

```
unicode_code = "00000061"
character = "\u" + unicode_code
```

A example would be appreciated.

Comment: Not with that many digits it won't.

Comment: changed it to "0061" and still didn't work.

Comment: Why not just `chr(61)` (or `unichr(61)` in Python 2)?

Answer (score 1):

[Literals are notations for **constant** values of some built-in types](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

> Unless an '`r`' or '`R`' prefix is present, escape sequences in
>   strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by
>   Standard C:
>
> - `…`
> - `\uxxxx`     Character with 16-bit hex value `xxxx` (Unicode only)
> - `\Uxxxxxxxx` Character with 32-bit hex value `xxxxxxxx` (Unicode only)
> - `…`

Unfortunately, neither `"\u" + "0061"` nor `"\U" + "00000061"` satisfy condition of *constant values* as they both are *expressions*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found about chr() which did what i wanted.